# To fix number of characters in JFormattedTextField to 300 usinf MaskFormatter

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield

I have seen code to fix number of characters in text field using MaskFormatter but that was for limited number i.e. 10 or 15 etc.. But for 300 characters do I need to put"#" 300 times? Is there any simple way of doing it. Please help

Comment: You'd have 300-digit numbers?

Comment: formatter.setPlaceholderCharacter('#');

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether there is a simple way but I'd use a mask formatter to employ some formatting on the numbers which might be quite complex, e.g. in the size of the digit blocks (e.g. 1-234-56789) and thus you'd probably have to completely define that mask string anyways.

A possible way to go might be to dynamically create the mask, e.g.

```
StringBuilder mask = new StringBuilder();
for( int i = 0; i < 300; i++ {
  mask.append("#");
}
```